# Why does Microsoft block .url attachments and not .htm in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, blocking, attachments

Outlook by default blocks `.url` attachments and not `.htm` – why?

Any dangerous URL that could be in `.url` file, could also easily be in a `.htm` file and could be launched using javascript automatically. I see the same risk with both attachments, but Microsoft treats it differently. Am I missing something here? How is a `.htm` file safer than `.url`?

What else could be in `.url` file that a hacker could not put in `.htm` file?

Comment: Maybe there is a known vulnerability with `.url` files which would cause contained data to be interpreted without user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable scripts and redirects through browser security settings if you desire to do so.

You'd need to disable `.url` file support completely for some protection against those.